# SignalR not mapped in startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have installed signalr in my project and registered it in startup class like this

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();          
    }
```

but I have an error in browser console

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is 
correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
    at Object.start (jquery.signalr-2.2.2.min.js:9)
    at notificationsmodule.js:2
```

I added this scripts to layout page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Notification/NotificationsModule.js"></script>
```

I have searched about this error and I find some solution that doesn't fix my problem like:
add this tags to web.config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Moadi.Web.Startup"/>
<appSettings/>
```

but when I do this the .NET Framework app fails with "Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0'"

Can anyone help me solving this issue

Comment: Did you create a asp.net core 2.0 project?

Comment: no it is a regular asp mvc project @Tester

Comment: Does your Startup class hass the [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(NameOfYourStartupClass))] Attribute? Then you do not need any avlues in appsettings. You can also name your Startup class Startup then it should be found outomatically. There are other possibilties: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup):

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself
Since OWIN was not configured in the creation of project. I manually deleted bin folder from project folder.